# How to go to a specific time of a video clip quickly in YouTube app?

Tags: youtube

Since the YouTube app has nowhere to input the URL, I cannot jump to a specific time to view it.

Dragging the player caret is very hard to make an accurate jump especially for a long clip

How to do that easily?

Comment: What if you browse YouTube on the browser?

Comment: I use YouTube app more often indeed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YouTube now has updated their player and to jump to small area, there is now a popup slider for us to pick the point.

Answer (score 5):

If you type/paste the URL with the time behind `#t=` into your browser on Android (I use Chrome, but others would presumably work the same way) you should get a popup asking you if you want to open the link in YouTube. This will open the video in the YouTube app and jump straight to the time defined.

Matt Cutts explains how to do this with the YouTube URL on [his blog](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/link-to-youtube-minute-second/). Try copy/pasting `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjDw3azfZWI#t=31m08s` into your browser as an example.

[image: YouTube Time URL Android]

Comment: The `#` option does still work.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can't do that in the YouTube app. I tried some third party apps as well and nothing came up. In addition, the [YouTube app's website](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=29422#/answer/1687337) also tells you to *...slide the scrubber below the video to jump to a different part of the video...*

So I guess the only option for you is to use your browser to view videos.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So boring ^^ For now with big video I will have difficulty to open the part I want to watch. Sliding by our thumb/finger may never get to the point we want it to

Comment: @NamG.VU Actually it is not *that* hard. In vertical orientation, go near a place where you want to jump to and slide to the time needed without releasing it. (e.g. to jump to `10:28`, press near `10:20` or so and slide till you see `10:28`)

Comment: The problem of big video is a "small move of fingef to the right" is equal to minutes not seconds as you are saying

Comment: well, Tue answer still stands. seems this is something you have to live with. And like I said, you can always use your browser to view the videos. :D

Answer (score 3):

Get the URL by e.g. sharing the video and copy the link, then just add `?t=` plus whatever time at end of the copied hyperlink followed with an `s` once you share, i.e. for `https://youtu.be/FswuhgCyMH4`, starting at 40 seconds would be `https://youtu.be/FswuhgCyMH4?t=40s`.

For adding minutes, add the number followed with an `m` plus the number of seconds followed with an `s`, e.g. `https://youtu.be/FswuhgCyMH4?t=1m30s`.

Answer (score 1):

On audio clips, I start a comment, then enter the desired timestamp(s) and go directly there. (e.g. `1:23`, `02:05`, `1:01:01`, etc.).

Not sure if you have to post, but you can always retract it (or explain yourself!).